# Warning about multiple operations with CM database upgrade to SDL Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, upgrade, database

We are currently doing an upgrade of a Tridion CMS to SDL Web 8.5.
We took a back up of the old CMS DB, restored it in our new SQL server, and we're now running the upgrade script.
However, this script gives us the following warning:

> "The analysis of your system has detected that Multiple Operations exist in the database. Proceeding with the upgrade will cause the deletion of those Multiple Operations."

Upon inspection of the tables, it does indeed look like the table `MULTIPLE_OPERATIONS` contains two records (I assume these are batch operations).
In the `ACTIVE` column of these rows, the values are all "`0`", so it looks as if all operations have finished.
[image]

Would there be a problem if we ignore this warning for our upgrade script and let it run, or should we first make sure this table is emptied by the old Tridion CMS before we take our backup ?

Answer (score 3):

For both operations TOTAL==DONE, and both operations have skipOnError="true", so it might be that bulk operations were executed with errors. You can examine OPERATIONS XML to see that. In this case operations are not deleted to allow admin to review errors.
In your case, I think, this warning can be ignored.